# One service, three methods that need to write into specific lines in one file (independently and arbitrarily). What's the best method?

Tags: java, android, java-io

So in my app I have 1 service, with three listener callback methods: `onCallStateChanged()`, `onSignalStrengthsChanged()`, and `onCellLocationChanged()`, that each need to write into specific lines into one file arbitrarily.

What is the best way to do it? The data in the file needs to be updated in real-time (i.e. accurate at any point in time).

Comment: Synchronize the access to the file in each of those methods such that only one at a time can change the file.

Comment: Thanks for the response. One question: doesn't Android already do that? If two things try to write into a same file, wouldn't the first writer get lock, and the second writer get blocked until the file is unlocked?

Comment: All of these `PhoneStateListener` callbacks execute on the main thread. In that case you don't need to synchronize access to the file since those methods cannot run in parallel.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is it you want to know? What have you tried? Are you having some issues?

Comment: You already have a problem defining your files as lines that need to be written separately via random access. Text files don't support random access in any meaningful way, because of the variable line lengths. You're going to have to use a binary file with fixed length records. Then it's just an exercise in synchronization and seeking. Note that Java file locks won't do it for you, because they are inter-process, not inter-thread.